# Implementing AppBrain banner-ad - Am I doing it right?

Tags: android, banner-ads

I tried AppBrain banner ads on my app recently. I am not sure if the ads are showing properly. This is what I see in my app

![Ads in my app]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xowh3.jpg

The add seems like a generic template whereas, their website shows different images for a sample of banner ads.

![Sample ads in AppBrain website]https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqFfV.jpg

The documentation says adding the view alone will automatically call the requestAd() function

> public void requestAd()
>
> Request an ad to be fetched. If a listener was set on this banner, that listener will be notified of the result. This method is automatically called once the banner is added to the view layout, so calling it manually is optional.

However, I did call the requestAd() in the activity also

```
AppBrainBanner banner;
```

In the onCreate

```
banner = findViewById(R.id.appBrainAdView);
banner.requestAd();
```

I contacted AppBrain 4-5 days ago and didn't receive any response yet. Am I implementing the ads right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is Mathijs from AppBrain.

Yes you're doing it right. The extra `requestAd()` is not needed, and our banners can show a number of different designs. The 'generic' one that requires a click before the user sees the apps he can install is the most common one, so it's normal you're seeing that one a lot.